# Laravel update key and value in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have key and value columns in db how can i update them from controller ?

How Can i update by key

```
$settings = \App\Setting::where('type','synrisk')->get();
$settings->fill($request->all());
$settings->save();
Session::flash('message', 'تم التعديل بنجاح');
return redirect()->route('about_us_admin');
```

My Form response

```
 _token: "zLiFs10lNkuIZxu2DPyPwetsA3HCaNlgLb9L1w45",
 full_name: "Mazen",
 email: "mazen@aramex.com",
```

My db

```
 {
    id: 4,
    key: "phone_number_1",
    value: "07777777",
    type: "Aramex",
    created_at: "2019-06-16 12:48:43",
    updated_at: "2019-06-16 12:48:43"
    },
    {
    id: 5,
    key: "phone_number_2",
    value: "07777777",
    type: "Aramex",
    created_at: "2019-06-16 12:48:43",
    updated_at: "2019-06-16 12:48:43"
    },
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ??  You are only getting full name and email coming through in request... what do you mean key and value ??

Comment: @alithedeveloper i'm saving the type of value like email in key and the email (example@gmail.com) in value

Comment: I didn't understand your DB structure. Can you add some more examples. Where is email? Where is full_name? Will  multiple row update for every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who may stumble upon this and needs help, I found `foreach` useful in this case senario, Good Luck

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
            if ($request->hasFile($key)) {
                $value = Storage::disk('public')->put('settings', $request->file($key));
                $setting->where('key', $key)->update(['value' => $value]);
            } else {
                $setting->where('key', $key)->update(['value' => $value]);
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do some thing like,

```
  $fullName = request()->only('full_name')

    $fullNameKeyValue = [
      'key' => array_key_first($fullName),
      'value' => array_key_first(array_flip($fullName))
    ];


    // You can extract this logic to a function and have checks in place as well
    // like is_array() and array_key_exists() . 

    $settings->fill($fullNameKeyValue);
    $settings->save();
```